# scikit-learn package successfully updated, but continues to use/show old version

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I just got access to a new server which has Python 2.7 and some packages already installed. However, I need the newest version of scikit-learn (0.18.0).

I tried to pip-upgrade the package, which returns the following affirmative message `Successfully installed scikit-learn Cleaning up...`

I used the following command, which worked for upgrading other packages (e.g. scipy):

```
OPENBLAS=/cluster/apps/openblas/0.2.13_seq/x86_64/gcc_5.2.0/lib python -m pip install --user --upgrade scikit-learn
```

When checking the version with `pip freeze` and `python -c 'import sklearn; print sklearn.__version__'` it continues to show the old version (0.17.1). In my home directory (I don't have root access) a folder named 'scikit_learn-0.18-py2.7.egg-info' was created.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I'm on Centos 6 and packages like numpy and scipy worked just fine

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was in the same situation as you, in order to get the correct version of sklearn, before importing it,
I added this line to my code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/your_user_name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
```

I am not quite sure about the path part, but basically I think it is

```
sys.path.insert(0, '$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that path is already part of the configuration. It still doesn't show up as the newest version. I was able to update packages like numpy and scipy w/o problems